# Is there a way to add the "Open Command Window Here" option to older versions of windows explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Whenever I need to work on an older version of Windows, I am incredibly frustrated by the lack of the "Open Command Window Here" extended option when you shift-right-click in explorer.  Is there any way to add this functionality on to older versions of windows?

Comment: Define older versions... Older than NT 6.2? Older than XP?

Comment: @AthomSfere I don't know if it was 7 or Vista when it was introduced, but the oldest versions I wish for this to work on are XP/Server2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make registry entry for that in older version of Windows. Type this in Notepad and save as CommandWindowHere.reg. Double click to run it. If you prefer, you can also make these entries manually using RegEdit directly.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt]@="Open Command Window Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\command]@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

Few other tweaks that you might like are listed [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-cool-registry-edits-and-tweaks-for-windows-xp/1468)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is:

- Highlight and copy the path from the address bar.
- Hit Win-R to bring up the Run dialog.
- Type: `cmd /k cd`, paste the path, and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Powertoys still has download to add exactly that to XP.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/CmdHerePowertoySetup.exe

It should work on server 2003 too.